# Authorization failure with AWS API Gateway

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, curl, aws-api-gateway

I have integrated AWS API Gateway with AWS Cognito User pool. The following curl command works.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization:<id token>" -d <json data> <https url>
```

However, authorization fails with the following Angularjs $http.put.
AWS cloudwatch logs show "user is unauthorized"

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
$http.put('https://<url>', <json data> )
    .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('success')
    }, function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('failure')
    });
```

How should the authorization token be set with $http.put?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to set the header for the request as the second argument in the `$http.put(<url>, options)...`.

So in your case, your code should look like this:

```
var options = {headers:  {
                        'Authorization': token,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }
              };

$http.put('https://<url>', <json data>, options);
```

You can check [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) to learn more about different ways of invoking the `$http.X` methods.

I hope this helps.